# java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: java, mysql, exception, jdbc, connection

The following code:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection m_connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost","root","root");
```

Throws this exception on `getConnection()`:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4006)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1694)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1244)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2397)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2430)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2215)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:813)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:334)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at db.Database.<init>(Database.java:91)
    at db.Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

**EDIT:**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, ServletException, SQLException 
    {

        try
        {
            Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/?user=root&password=rootpassword"); 
            Statement   s = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
            int result = s.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE databasename");
        }


        catch ( Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Produces :

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4006)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1694)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1244)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2397)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2430)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2215)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:813)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:334)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at db.Main.main(Main.java:19)
```

Comment: are you able to connect using mysql GUI client like SqlYog or PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: @ftom2: Yes , I can access `phpmyadmin` successfully .

Comment: Are you sure the **Username** and the **Password** so provided is right ? Seesm to me there is no such user as **root** :( Not sure though, but don't you have to provide the **Database Name** too like `Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost;database=mywebsitedb;user=sa;password=thatstrue;");`

Comment: @GagandeepBali: think once again about it: If the login was wrong, how would the OP be able to access it by phpmyadmin then?

Comment: @BalusC : Actually never used `phpmyadmin`, though I had used `SQLServer` sometimes, those fields are autofilled by default, and we forget them. That's why that guess was as comments, else it could become an answer, if I thought that is really the case (which it may or may not be the case).  Though since you are offended by that comment, I would be very much wrong in asking the same , my bad :-)

Comment: There are 2 things you need to establish - are you a valid user, do you have the authority (privileges) to perform the action. Authority takes the form of a specific privilege from a specified host. It is possible to answer both questions before introducing any Java. Personally, I'd use the command line to connect to my sql as the user specified, e.g. 'mysql -uroot -prootpassword', then execute the command 'create database mydb'. If this works you can drop the database and head over to your Java code.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As you are creating a database from scratch, you could use:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/?user=root&password=rootpassword"); 
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("CREATE DATABASE databasename");
int result = ps.executeUpdate();
```

Here is an [identical scenario](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,99321,102211#msg-102211).

Comment: If I don't have any database at all ? and I want to create the database using java code , and NOT manually in `phpmyadmin` , then `databaseName` is not relevant ?

Comment: I was working on one of my application, the connectivity between the code and the database was fine. I started getting this error suddenly, dont know why and what to do.

Answer (score 67):

This can help you:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '%password%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Execute it with command line or some GUI tool.

Don't forget to replace `%password%` with real password.

Comment: @evg I have successfully executed this query but still not getting rid from this error

Comment: @evg Whether the above solution works for the below one also. Here instead of localhost, IP address is mentioned as below
**java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'1.1.22.85' (using password: YES).**

Comment: If anyone facing Access Denied problem after applying this solution then you can apply [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12670234/9340694) solution for life easy. Thanks

Answer (score 29):

This is specific to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and MySQL 5.x
Followed this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-18-04)
Follow everything from here onwards:

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation

sudo mysql
```

Once logged into MySQL then from the MySQL prompt execute these commands:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Now verify that the table has the password for the root

```
SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;
```

This solved my issue and now i am able to login.

Comment: "Now verify that the table has the password for the root" - and what if it does not? ;)

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem, but the differemce was: I didn't executed my JavaApp from `localhost`, but from a remote PC. So I got something like `java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'a.remote.ip.adress' (using password: YES)`
To solve this, you can simply login to phpMyAdmin, go to `Users`, click `add user` and enter the host from which you want to execute your JavaApp (or choose `Any Host`)

Answer (score 9):

you can use this

```
   static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
   static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/YOUR_DB_NAME";


   static final String USER = "root";
   static final String PASS = "YOUR_ROOT_PASSWORD"; 

  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
```

you have to give the right root password .

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue like below

```
"java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)". Problem was "WRONG PASSWORD".
```

Copy and paste the query as-it-is in the shell to check whether it gives the desired output or not. Small errors consumes more time.

Comment: I had same problem. I was wrong with the password specified in the application.properties. It should be same as your local database password.

Answer (score 5):

This appears to mostly happens when the MySQL username and password are not correct. Check your MySQL username and password.

Comment: Thanks for this. My issue had to do with an incorrect password. I was deploying an app to a Kubernetes cluster, and the password was encrypted in Kubernetes secrets. All I had to do was view the Kubernetes secret in the cluster, de-encrypt the password from base64 to json, which revealed the incorrect password, and then I corrected the password and deployed. This time it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

You should specify the db you are connecting to:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this....

```
public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException{

    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String url    = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
    String username = "root";
    String password = "vicky";            // Change it to your Password
    System.setProperty(driver,"");

    return DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
}
```

Comment: Why exactly would it solve the concrete problem? You are not explaining the cause in any way.

Answer (score 1):

I was hitting the same issue. Added mysql service port number(3307), resolved the issue.

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/?" + "user=root&password=password");
```

Answer (score 1):

Although this may not be the cause of your issue, you'll get the same error if there are two MySQL services running on the same port. You can check on windows by looking at the list of services in the services tab of Task Manager.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This Exception is also caused due to version mismatch of mysql db and your pom.xml/jar.

Make sure your pom.xml/jar version is higher than your mysql db version.
Because higher versions are compatible with lower version's, but the same is not true for the inverse.

Solution's for java project

- Replace the Jar with suitable version.

Solution for maven based

- Change the dependency Version in pom.xml

Solution for spring boot
 - Override the spring boot dependency by adding 

    5.1.5.Final

Answer (score 1):

I am using Spring Boot 2.2.6(Windows) and faced the same issue when I tried the run the application:
***java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)***

What solved my problem:

1. Create a new user (from the MySQL workbench or a similar GUI which you might be using)
2. Grant DBA priviledges (Tick the DBA checkbox) also from the GUI
3. Run the spring boot application.

Or follow the @evg solution to grant privilegdes from command line in Linux env.

Comment: I am using Spring Boot 2.6.2(Windows) and faced the same issue when I tried your solution but not able to resolve my issue:

Answer (score 1):

My `application.properties` looked something like this

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb

spring.datasource.username=root

spring.datasource.password=root
```

The only thing worked for me is to maven clean and then maven install.

Answer (score 1):

When I'm running a springboot project, the application.yml configuration is like this：

```
server:
  port: 8080
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lof?serverTimezone=GMT
    username: root
    password: root
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Notice that there isn't quotation marks around the password. And I can run this project in my windows System.

But when I try to deploy to the server, I have the problem and I fix it by changing the application.yml to:

```
server:
  port: 8080
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lof?serverTimezone=GMT
    username: root
    password: "root"
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Answer (score 1):

Add port number (something like 3306) in:

```
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:urport","root","root");
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I created a new user with name admin and used it...

```
CREATE USER 'admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost'
WITH GRANT OPTION;

CREATE USER 'admin'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'%'
WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to change my SQL setup (in my host, Dreamhost in my case) to allow the username to access the database from other hosts, not just Dreamhost since I'm running a program from the IDE on my computer. I did that for now by adding % to the list of Allowable Hosts. It now works!

Comment: I should add that this is similar to #munchkins approach but from the SQL control panel end.

Answer (score 0):

The order of declaring:

- Driver
- Connection string
- username
- password

If we declaring in order

- Connection string
- username
- password
- Driver

the application will fail

Answer (score 0):

1. use correct jar (with correct version)
2. give root user host-independent access or create a user

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution worked as by changing the url format to:
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/w3schools?user=###&password=###");
make sure to add proper jar to class path and use the driver
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Answer (score 0):

This resolved issue for me.

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.cfe TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue, My connection string is valid and username and password also valid, even user has sufficient privileges to access database.

I solved this issue by deleting temporary folder created by MySQL(**Please take backup before deleting any folders** so in case if it not works then you can place that files again).

Default folder location for temp and connection files of MySQL in Windows is:

> C:\ProgramData\MySQL

I deleted(taken backup) of below folder:

> C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server \Data\sys

**Note:** Before deleting any items make sure that MySQL service is not started or else it would not allow to delete any files

And It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine for me while using same password after executing the following statement:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DATABASE_NAME? useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

**Go to your phpmyadmin database**

Create a database called DATABASE_NAME and go to priviledges and check the users who have priviledges in the database and use them the default is "root"

Answer (score 0):

Due to below reason I created new user and password for mysql, now I am able to connect successfully. if your password is in encoded format please create new password

[https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql#:~:text=There%20is%20a,mysql_native_password%20plugin%20instead%3A](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql#:%7E:text=There%20is%20a,mysql_native_password%20plugin%20instead%3A)

There is a known issue with some versions of PHP that causes problems with caching_sha2_password. If you plan to use this database with a PHP application — phpMyAdmin, for example — you may want to create a user that will authenticate with the older, though still secure, mysql_native_password plugin instead:

Answer (score 0):

Solved! change `localhost` by `127.1.1.1` in your java code, with `localhost` not connect and throws this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes MySQL server, while creating the user, sets the authentication type other than 'Standard'. The user I was using had the authentication type set to '*caching_sha_password*'. Because of this, the connection was failing.

I created a new user via MySQL Workbench with all the privileges and set the authentication type to 'Standard', and the exception was gone.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Install mysql-server for developer from here: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=526407 and configure it according to your properties (username & password)

After you installed it, open the MySql app and configure it with username & password and db-name.

Comment: I believe the OP has already downloaded MySQL and he has probably already configured it and I guess he configured it incorrectly otherwise he wouldn't be getting an error. So how does your answer help resolve the problem that is described in the posted question?

Answer (score -1):

I encountered this error. The problem was that I had the wrong database name.

Answer (score -1):

If you are connecting a remote mysql server from your local machine using java see the below steps.
Error :
"java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'xxxxx'@'101.123.163.141' (using password: YES) "

for remote access may be cpanel or others grant the remote access for your local ip address.

In the above error message: "101.123.163.141" is my local machine ip. So First we have to give remote access in the Cpanel-> Remote MySQL®. Then run your application to connect.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
    "jdbc:mysql://www.xyz.com/abc","def","ghi");  
//here abc is database name, def is username and ghi        
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from employee");  
    while(rs.next())  
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+" "+rs.getString(2)+"  
                          "+rs.getString(3));  
con.close();
```

Hope it will resolve your issue.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I also have this problem, this solved it.

Change the:

`Sring url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone=UTC&user=root&password=password";`

Set:

`"serverTimezone=UTC"` is `"Unified standard world time"`.
`"useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8"` is `"Solve Chinese garbled"`.

Although my database have not any Chinese words. But it is working.
Reference from https://www.cnblogs.com/EasonJim/p/6906713.html

Comment: Please format your code and do not deliver a link to an external page here if possible. Sum up everything directly into your post. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a MySql workbench, go to the home page of workbench, right click on your database, copy the JDBC connection string, and paste it into the Java program.

Answer (score -2):

be sure that the port you are using in:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:8000/database
```

is the same that MySQL uses on your machine:
check for it with this command in MySQL CLI:

```sql
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'port';
```

Comment: The OP (from 10 years ago, I suspect they've moved on by now) shows `access denied` and not some sort of failed connection. So the port number is not likely the problem, since they must have been able to connect in order to have the credentials rejected.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32182452)