# can't login to mysql server after GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES

Tags: mysql

I had the same problem mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922323/java-sql-sqlexception-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password), so I logged in as `webuser` on mydomain.de/phpmyadmin and executed the query from the most pupolar answer:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'webuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'webuser' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

After that, I'm not able to login to phpmyadmin anymore with user=webuser.

```
 #1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server.
```

But on my website (subdomain.mydomain.de), where I use the same login to connect to my mysql-database, everything is ok.

What have I done and how can I fix this?

Comment: Are you able to login via terminal ? Have you used FLUSH PRIVILEGES; after the granting? Check the user table and the privileges from the webuser via the root user.

Comment: yes I am. And on my website I can execute queries with using this users name and pw for db connection

Comment: Is mysql running on the same box as phpMyAdmin?

Comment: yes both run at the same machine. see my changes in the question.

Comment: As I just read here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5016587/1654763 , i should remove these privileges from `webuser`, because I use this account for my website. I could create a simple php file which just connects to mysql-db and execute a query which removes these global privileges - but how should this query look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved: I logged in as root and changed the password for `webuser`.
I think the command `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'webuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'webuser' WITH GRANT OPTION;` resettet the password for `webuser`