# Cannot find the error in connceting to database

Tags: java, mysql, database, connection

Almost all answers I read say either my databse name or pw is wrong but I am 100% sure it isnt.Here is a http error description :
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

If anyone can help me, I would be really greatful.Still a begginer at programming, dont go hard on me. :)

Here is a line of code i used at my other projects and it worked fine for me:

```
<sql:setDataSource var = "snapshot" driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/project" user = "root"  password = "######"/>
```

Comment: The tag you're missing is [tag:mysql] (or [tag:mariadb]). I've added the former. This is a **very common** MySQL configuration problem.

Comment: Are you trying to create a database from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

Execute this by some command line or GUI

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '%password%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Replace `%password%` with your password.

And if the above solution can't help you go and find some [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922323/java-sql-sqlexception-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password)