# java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'. Could not create connection to database server

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

My Spring boot boot application is running properly on my local system i.e., Windows 10, but when I am trying to deploy the application on Ubuntu 18.04 os, where MySql is installed locally. it is throwing error while starting up the application saying

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Below one is my application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/madagascar?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=qwerty
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto =update
server.port=8080
```

Here is my pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>co.yabx</groupId>
    <artifactId>kyc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>kyc</name>
    <description>KYC</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.46</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Here is the complete error

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2096) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2021) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:776) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:386) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:735) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:667) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:482) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar!/:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.TargetDatabaseImpl.prepare(TargetDatabaseImpl.java:38) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:57) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:134) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:101) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:472) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) [hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) [spring-orm-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) [spring-orm-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) [spring-orm-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) [spring-orm-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078) [spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) [spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) [spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.4.RELEASE]
        at co.yabx.kyc.app.KYCApplication.main(KYCApplication.java:10) [classes!/:1.0]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [kyc-1.0.jar:1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [kyc-1.0.jar:1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [kyc-1.0.jar:1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [kyc-1.0.jar:1.0]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3976) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3912) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:871) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1714) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1224) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2190) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2037) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar!/:5.1.46]
        ... 58 common frames omitted
```

Kindly help me in starting up the application.

Comment: Can you connect from commandline?

Comment: @Andronicus yes i am able to connect to mysql with command line, but my spring boot application is unable to connect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922323/java-sql-sqlexception-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password)

Comment: @RameshSubramanian yes, helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> sudo mysql

Next, check which authentication method each of your MySQL user accounts use with the following command:

> SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;

Output

```
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
| user             | authentication_string                     | plugin                | host      |
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
| root             |                                           | auth_socket           | localhost |
| mysql.session    | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE | mysql_native_password | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE | mysql_native_password | localhost |
| debian-sys-maint | *CC744277A401A7D25BE1CA89AFF17BF607F876FF | mysql_native_password | localhost |
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can see that the root user does in fact authenticate using the auth_socket plugin. To configure the root account to authenticate with a password, run the following ALTER USER command. Be sure to change password to a strong password of your choosing, and note that this command will change the root password you set in Step 2:

> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';

Then, run FLUSH PRIVILEGES which tells the server to reload the grant tables and put your new changes into effect:

> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Check the authentication methods employed by each of your users again to confirm that root no longer authenticates using the auth_socket plugin:

> SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;

Output

```
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
| user             | authentication_string                     | plugin                | host      |
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
| root             | *3636DACC8616D997782ADD0839F92C1571D6D78F | mysql_native_password | localhost |
| mysql.session    | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE | mysql_native_password | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE | mysql_native_password | localhost |
| debian-sys-maint | *CC744277A401A7D25BE1CA89AFF17BF607F876FF | mysql_native_password | localhost |
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can see in this output that the root MySQL user now authenticates using a password. Once you confirm this on your own server, you can exit the MySQL shell:

> exit