# springboot can't connect with mysql8.0

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

access to localhost database was dennied

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:829) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:449) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:242) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
```

this is application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    username: root
    password: 000000
    url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/student?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&serverTimezone=CST
```

this is mysql user table:
[image: mysql table]

I have tried to chang the yml file and database settings but failed,is it the problem about the mysql version?

Comment: Double check the credential you provided.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access Denied for user 'root'@'localhost' - Spring Boot & MySQL connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61595373/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-spring-boot-mysql-connection)

Answer (score 0):

> is it the problem about the mysql version?

No, It's not. You are trying to connect to the server with wrong credentials. Just check your credentials (username and password).

Also, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61693994/10109156).

Comment: is your password really 6 zeros, I mean you can easily type more or less zeros by mistake.