# Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction. Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' on Linux VPS

Tags: mysql, linux, spring-mvc, vps

I'm setting up my Spring MVC project on a Linux VPS. My project works fine on my home PC, but on the VPS it cannot connect to database.
This is my datasource config file inside the project:

```
# DataSource 
ds.database-driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
ds.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myData?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
ds.username=root
ds.password=password
```

Everything is the same as the MySQL infomation on the VPS. I only deployed the war file and run, didn't do anything else.

Comment: Have you tried to connect to mysql in command line on your vps?

Comment: Wrong username or password, but you shouldn't be using the root login for anything except DB administration/

Comment: i found the solution here of user Ashu: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922323/java-sql-sqlexception-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password