# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in eclipse when connecting with jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'am trying to access sql database from eclipse Java IDE using jdbc connectivity. But I'am encountering with a error "Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)". Please help me.

```
package language;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class DBconnection {
    private static String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/language";
    private static String userName="root";
    private static String passWord="rootuser";
    


    public  static Connection getConnection() throws Exception{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,passWord);
    }

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IuK9.png) See the error image!

**SELECT Host,User,plugin,authentication_string FROM mysql.user;**

```
+-----------+------------------+-----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Host      | User             | plugin                | authentication_string                                                  |
+-----------+------------------+-----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| localhost | chinnu           | mysql_native_password | *88FBBBF3EA3E4189FF5764256AC3B39A15CB2328                              |
| localhost | mysql.infoschema | caching_sha2_password | $A$005$THISISACOMBINATIONOFINVALIDSALTANDPASSWORDTHATMUSTNEVERBRBEUSED |
| localhost | mysql.session    | caching_sha2_password | $A$005$THISISACOMBINATIONOFINVALIDSALTANDPASSWORDTHATMUSTNEVERBRBEUSED |
| localhost | mysql.sys        | caching_sha2_password | $A$005$THISISACOMBINATIONOFINVALIDSALTANDPASSWORDTHATMUSTNEVERBRBEUSED |
| localhost | newuser          | mysql_native_password | *F071E3EB4C99F6E1F1CDD5E1031193757E974214                              |
| localhost | root             | mysql_native_password | *992C4DB09F487A275976576CCFA554F7D20A4207                              |
+-----------+------------------+-----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922323/java-sql-sqlexception-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922323/java-sql-sqlexception-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password)

Comment: The answer provided in this link is to change the syntax of code, Where as my code and username and password are perfect, I doubled checked them. But getting errors in eclipse.

Comment: @progman I have updated the question, Please find me a solution.

Comment: @CharanKondaveeti Please edit your question to include the MySQL server version you are using and the exact library version of your MySQL connector in java.

Comment: @CharanKondaveeti Also add the value of the server configuration variable `skip-name-resolve` to your question (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_skip_name_resolve) and the content of your `/etc/hosts` file regarding `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` (assuming you are using a unix system).