# I deleted all the users from phpmyadmin and now it is saying '#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I deleted all the users from phpmyadmin and now it is saying

> '#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password:
>   NO)'

It will not let me access '**phpmyadmin**' at all anymore.

I am using a mac and I have been spending hours trying to find out how to solve this problem.

It says below

> 'phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server
>   rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and
>   password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to
>   the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.'

Can anyone help me?

Thanks
Josh

Comment: Key is in "I deleted all the users". You need to add the user and it basically fools this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: I am using a macbook so it does not make any sense to me.. can you explain how i can do this.. or how i can start being able to access my phpmyadmin?

Comment: How using macbook makes any difference? Did you read the article?

Comment: 2. Stop the MySQL server if it is running. For a server that is running as a Windows service, go to the Services manager: From the Start menu, select Control Panel, then Administrative Tools, then Services. Find the MySQL service in the list and stop it. << thats a windows term and doesn't stat how to do it on mac.. is there a mac help guide? and also where is the system administator? as i don't know where that is?

Comment: Yes, there is. On the same page. C.5.4.1.2 Resetting the Root Password: Unix Systems just continue reading. But you will need to also add the user if you have deleted it.

Comment: I'm sorry it doesn't make any sense that guide to me.. i can not add a new user as it won't let me access on ANY of the phpmyadmin.. it completely denying me now :( it was working but i deleted every user by accident.. i am a beginner and using phpmyadmin to learn but i can't fix it :(

Comment: It is simple: you can't add the users back using phpmyadmin. You have to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Try to assign a password to root user. I believe it *cannot* be blank.

Comment: it does not let me access any permissions.. it denies me from everything.

Answer (score 0):

first of all it is a bad idea to delete all users from phpmyadmin (although I did the same and got a lot of problems after that). There are some solutions: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180893/mysql-said-cannot-connect-invalid-settings-xampp). You find in these discussion several steps to take you back to phpmyadmin. But if you are interesting in my solution:

1. I've deleted completely xampp from my PC (All folders and files with name XAMPP). After I've searched for the rest file in the directory where I've previously installed it, and delete them as well.
2. Reinstalled the XAMPP with phpmyadmin. Done. You're good to go!