# Access denied on phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Hi I can't seem to get any access or connect for that matter to the phpMyAdmin page when I'm using XAMPP. I already inputted the password on the MySQL and Apache config but I'm still getting an error page. This is what I get, anyone know what I should do?
[image: error page]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql said: Cannot connect: invalid settings. xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180893/mysql-said-cannot-connect-invalid-settings-xampp)

Answer (score 0):

The new phpmyadmin has done few changes regarding security.

Follow-up standard document to resolve.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-18-04