# phpmyadmin not running on xampp or wampp server?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to connect a html form to my sql database using php file and on xampp server,please help me I need to sumbit a project website to my teacher next week.
I have attached the snip of the xamp server if it is of any help.
Its my first time using localhost server.

I have also tried wamp server but non of these method working i have checked other methods here on stack and tried those to but they are not working

I want to send data from my html form to my database using a local host to show to my teacher that my website is working properly.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7EEx.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5G2g.png)

Comment: change your port `3306` to `3307` in `my.ini`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XAMPP - MySQL shutdown unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly)

Comment: I have changed the port now the server is running but phpmyadmin is still now running it says **access denied** i have the added that snip in my question too now

Comment: restart your serve.

Comment: I am giving you two links. Please follow these and see what works for you - 1. https://vincenttechblog.com/solved-mysql-error-cannot-connect/

Comment: 2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180893/mysql-said-cannot-connect-invalid-settings-xampp

Comment: its still not working, I have even restarted my laptop !!!

Comment: are you using skype on your laptop?

Comment: Did you try the steps these two provided links? Did you use a password during install the xampp?

Comment: i have read both the links you gave me they both show that we need to go configure a link in mysql **config** but that link is not in my mysql **config** the link which was written there is ** config.inc.php**

Comment: no im not using  skype

Comment: Did you use password during install?

Comment: https://pureinfotech.com/install-xampp-windows-10/

Comment: no i left it empty i was told that i can login phpmyadmin by using "root"(which) was and i to added as my  name and left password blank

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49948350/phpmyadmin-on-mysql-8-0

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall xampp, and wamp. After that, just install one of them.

Comment: I had only wamp server it didnt worked so i uninstalled that, then i installed xampp thats why i have written in my question that its not working on both of them.

Comment: Oh i see on image description part 2, that is another mysqld service was running on your windows machine, it means each mysqld service run, it use a port to work. i think your windows run two or more instance mysqld server, maybe from your xampp or wampp, because both of them not clearly uninstalled. Try to restart your windows, and then just delete them. if it unable to delete, try to boot your windows on safe mode.

Comment: All my friends are using it phpmyadmin on wamp server but mine wasnt workings then someone suggested me to changed to xampp now its not working, if you can say with guarantee if i  can uninstall xampp and reinstall it.

Comment: Try to boot in safe mode, and just delete the files on C:/xampp and C:/wampp

Comment: Hey, i read on above, about another comment to change the port mysqld server to 3307, it's right way, why must be change? The default port in mysql is 3306, if you cannot start service mysql, its indicate the port 3306 has been used by another program. After you change the port and success run mysqld service, the next step is change configuration in your phpmyadmin. Yes you must change the code inside directory C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php, open it in text editor, find line of code start with $cfg['Servers][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1'; change host to 127.0.0.1:3307, and then save.