# Access Denied Error when accessing phpmyadmin from xampp

Tags: php, xampp, mysql-workbench

I am having immense trouble with accessing, localhost/phpmyadmin, from xampp, a web-server solution stack package software. I have looked all over the web and other forums but found nothing. I have the error #2054. I have a picture of the error attached

[image: Error Message Picture]. Please can someone help me? Thank you so much.

Comment: Have a look on this question [mysql said: Cannot connect: invalid settings. xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180893/mysql-said-cannot-connect-invalid-settings-xampp)

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the file config.inc.php, please try change the line:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
```

to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

it means the phpmyadmin load the login by cookie part instead of config you need to set the root's password in it, but not recommend.